# glassfish3 deploy error: Application ... is already deployed in this domain

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am trying to deploy my war file into glassfish 3, but it fails to do so:

```
./asadmin deploy --force=true myapp.war
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Application myapp is already 
deployed in this domain. Please use create-application-ref command to create 
application reference on target server. Please see server.log for more 
details.
Command deploy failed.
```

*server.log* says basically the same message and nothing else. I've set logging level to FINEST and it is still just the same, a lot of messages about parsing web.xml and then boom:

```
[#|2018-03-27T14:09:43.912+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Application myapp is already deployed in this domain. Please use create-application-ref command to create application reference on target server|#]
```

But if I do undeploy *myapp* is not found, neither it is shown by `asadmin list-applications`. Is there any way to understand what is wrong and fix it?

> UPDATE: So far I ended up reading glassfish sources, and this is very
>   time consuming. No answer found up to now, though. Humanity, this is
>   one of those rare cases when I really need your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this was outrageously stupid and completely because I wanted to skip details about glassfish in general.

My problem was that I manually added `<application>` into `domain.xml`, completely sure that it is done manually. I have supported glassfish hosted apps a lot, redeployed, reconfigured, but never added a new app.

No any clue was given by `asadmin` and `server.log` to understand it quickly, so I'd spent 4 hours reading glassfish sources before I had a hint. Finally I removed `<application>` tag that I added myself and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

deploy by glasfish console

error>Application … is already deployed in this domain

> Applications>Application Targets>Manage Targets

select your target>save

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and [@dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529327/2915423)'s solution works for me.

Just to be clear I had to delete the lines starting with `->` from within my `domain.xml` template in order to be able to autodeploy w/out problems; as seen in these snippets:

```
  <servers>                                                                        
    <server config-ref="server-config" name="server">                              
->    <application-ref ref="portal" virtual-servers="server"></application-ref> 
      <application-ref ref="__admingui" virtual-servers="__asadmin"></application-ref>
      <resource-ref ref="jdbc/__TimerPool"></resource-ref>                         
      <resource-ref ref="jdbc/__default"></resource-ref>                           
      <resource-ref ref="jdbc/__derby"></resource-ref>                             
      <resource-ref ref="concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService"></resource-ref>
      <resource-ref ref="concurrent/__defaultManagedScheduledExecutorService"></res ... >
```

and

```
  <applications>                                                                   
->  <application context-root="/portal" deployment-time="3867" object-type="user" ... >
->    <property name="archiveType" value="war"></property>                         
->    <property name="cdiDevModeEnabled" value="false"></property>                 
->    <property name="appLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applic ... " >
->    <property name="defaultAppName" value="portal"></property>                   
->    <module name="portal">                                                       
->      <engine sniffer="cdi"></engine>                                            
->      <engine sniffer="security"></engine>                                       
->      <engine sniffer="web"></engine>                                            
->    </module>                                                                    
->  </application>                                                                 
  </applications>
```